# How do I exclude a specific URL in a filter in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have a basic application filter config that looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationFilterConfig {

    /**
    * Check if user is logged in
    */
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean applicationFilterRegistration() {

        // created a collections that need logins to be validated.
        ArrayList<String> urlPatterns = new ArrayList<String>();
        urlPatterns.add("/home");
        urlPatterns.add("/about");
        urlPatterns.add("/contact");
        // ... 

        LoginFilter loginFilter = new LoginFilter();
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(); 
        registration.setFilter(loginFilter);
        registration.setUrlPatterns(urlPatterns);
        registration.setOrder(1);
        return registration;

    } 


}
```

However, the list `urlPatterns` grows to be very long, even when using the star annotation (e.g. `/employees/*`). The main reason why I don't just use `/*` is because I don't want to require login validation for my login page. If I did, it'd create an infinite loop of redirects.

Does the `FilterRegistrationBean` class allow you to apply a filter to all URL patterns *except* certain patterns?

I could put everything except the login page in a directory and set my URL pattern to be `/subdirectory/*` but that adds an unnecessary level of depth to every file in my webapp.

Comment: The best you can do is to include all URLs and then have a whitelist or a blacklist inside your filter itself. If you don't want to filter it, just pass it along the chain before anything else.

Comment: I'm using JWT and I followed this great tutorial : https://auth0.com/blog/securing-spring-boot-with-jwts/ . it now works as I expect.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`FilterRegistrationBean` doesnot provide(atleast until now) any method to exclude **URL patterns**. But it can be taken care from from `Filter` implementation(in this case its `LoginFilter`). Implement `LoginFilter` by extending `OncePerRequestFilter` which has a method called `shouldNotFilter`() which can be overriden to suit your needs.

```
    public class LoginFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

        private List<String> excludeUrlPatterns = new ArrayList<String();

        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException
        {
            // Implementation....
        }

       @Override
       protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException 
       {
           // Populate excludeUrlPatterns on which one to exclude here
       }

    }
```

For more details you can follow this [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7426)